Is Kakashi mangekyo sharingan different?
I am re-watching this great show, however I noticed something that caught my eye and made me ask this question is kakashi's mangekyo different, because as we know in the episode "Five Kage Summit Eve" we see Obito use his mangekyo to travel( Its like a teleportation jutsu except that he goes through the kamui dimension. Meanwhile we've never seen kakashi teleport himself he is only able to use kamui on other objects like in episode 82 "Team 10" where he  uses it on deidara's arm and episode 159 "Kakashi" where he uses it on the nail that pain had thrown and the missile that was fired at choji. So what make kakashi's sharingan abilities different from obitos, and does this mean that all the other mangekyo users have a similar trait?

I don't quite have the patience to write a full answer with references, but the size of it is that mangekyo sharingan having specialized abilities in each eye is a thing in Naruto, going back to Itachi having Tsukuyomi in the left eye and Amaterasu in the right eye. This seemingly applies to the kamuis, but later on Kakashi actually manages to figure out how to use his kamui to teleport himself. That may possibly imply that long range kamui is the left-eye ability, intangibility is the right-eye ability (I don't recall Kakashi ever doing it with just one eye) and self-teleportation is shared.

This question is similar to: Why couldn't Kakashi pass through things?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Of course it is different. You can tell by looking at the black shapes in their sharingan eyes.
Look!
Kakashi's Mangekyo Sharingan:

Itachi's Mangekyo Sharingan:

And they also have different abilities/techniques.
But Kakashi's Mangekyo Sharingan is identical to Obito’s because the Sharingan is a gift from Obito Uchiha. So they both use the kamui technique.
EDIT:
Hmmm.... let me think.... I can only offer two possibilities now that I thought about it and looked it up.
1.) An Uchiha can use the sharingan at its full potential
2.) The reason behind it is the difference between the functioning of both eyes.
Resource: https://www.sportskeeda.com/anime/naruto-why-kakashi-able-use-kamui-s-intangibility

Yes I know that each sharingan user sharingan is different but my question was obitos ability uses transportation on himself while kakashis uses it on other objects

Hmmm.... let me think.... I can only offer two possibilities now that I thought about it and looked it up.

1.) An Uchiha can use the sharingan at its full potential

2.) The reason behind it is the difference between the functioning of both eyes.

Resource: https://www.sportskeeda.com/anime/naruto-why-kakashi-able-use-kamui-s-intangibility

I see, I understand that kakashi's left has a long distance while obitos is close distance.

But what would that mean if madara had given someone one of his eyes, say the right eye, that has the ability to reverse time in battle. What would the left eye be able to do. For example, sasukes left eye manipulates the shape and form of the amaterasu while the right casts it.

Hmmmm..... I'm not so sure, but that is a Good Question. Well, I actually never saw any of the Shinobi from the Uchiha Clan who have the power to reverse time. However, I guess if I were the creator of Naruto, I would say that the left eye would have the ability to freeze the enemy in place for a few seconds (like how you stop making movements when time is froze). If that makes sense in a way.

Eye is same but functionalities are different: Why couldn't Kakashi pass through things?

I should have known that the functionalities are different even if the eyes are the same. No wonder Kakashi couldn't make himself untouchable just like Obito can.
